# Using Selenium to Accept Alert and then Login

Tags: c#, selenium

I using C# to access a Government website that has an alert on accessing the site. I am able to acknowledge the alert, but the driver still has the original html in the page source so I am not able to access the Log In element of the site.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.afway.af.mil");

IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but haven't found the correct google search yet to give me the answer. Anyone have any ideas on how to refresh the driver.PageSource so I can access / select the Log In element?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` to switch back to the original window.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I updated my script from above, apparently the URL that worked last week with default.asp appended, isn't working this week :(